# Searching a line from text file

Tags: splunk

I have a file with semi colon ; delimited text file. It has been indexed in splunk.

```
INSERT INTO `account` VALUES ('abc');
INSERT INTO `account` VALUES ('xyz');
INSERT INTO `account` VALUES ('pqr');
INSERT INTO `account` VALUES ('mnp');
```

When I search for "pqr" it should show only 1 line. It is currently showing the next line "mnp" as well. There is no timestamp in the file and splunk still is grouping the lines by date-time. for e.g. all the lines mentioned above listed as a group under 06/09/2011 19:01:17.000

How do I return only one line while searching from a semi-colon delimited file?

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no timestamp, Splunk may be having difficulty determining if this is a single event (with 4 lines) or 4 separate events. All data is timestamped in Splunk. If incoming data does not have a timestamp, Splunk will assign the arrival time as the timestamp - and data arriving "simultaneously" may be interpreted as a single event.

To tell Splunk that your incoming data should be processed as "one event per line,"  put the following in $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/system/local/props.conf

```
[yoursourcetype]  
SHOULD_LINEMERGE=false  
DATETIME_CONFIG = CURRENT
```

IF your events could be multiple lines and the semicolor (;) separates events, use the following instead

```
[yoursourcetype]  
MUST_BREAK_AFTER = ;  
DATETIME_CONFIG = CURRENT
```

If you have a choice, the first option is much more efficient.  In both cases, I have included the DATEIME_CONFIG to tell Splunk that there is no embedded timestamp; this will speed input processing.

Finally, substitute "yoursourcetype" with the sourcetype of your data in the stanzas.